# On Windows shows an error message "socket re-usage" though there is no intend to do so

Tags: windows, tcp, port

Our CI has a massive parallel workload, we see this error message on the client on trying to connect to a (local) server on Windows:

```
connect() failed with #10048 - Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

and all connection related tests will thet fail after this.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @IInspectable I was rather wanting to share my answer with others than having others find solutions for me, since it took me 3 weeks to find out, and I wanted others in the same situation to have something to find by google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TCP stack has 65536 possible ports. A tcp connection involves 2 ports:

- the one the server bound - i.e. port 80 for HTTP
- the source port the client originates its connection from

Per convention (and configuration), these 65k ports are devided into ranges. The client ports are by default taken from the upper range above a preconfigured port. The windows net command can show its current configuration state:

```
netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp
Protocol tcp Dynamic Port Range
---------------------------------
Start Port      : 49152
Number of Ports : 16384
```

So, tcp ports are a limited resource and if massively used you can run out of them. Another thing worsening the situation is, that
sockets have a life in the kernel after death: [`TIME_WAIT`](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html).
Sockets in this state are left lingering around for a certain time, so the TCP Stack can handle late comming packages - for 2 minutes by default - even on the loopback interface (SRSLY Microsoft?).

The windows IP stack can configure these portranges and timings:

- HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\MaxUserPort influences the port ranges
- [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\TcpTimedWaitDelay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/settings-that-can-be-modified-to-improve-network-performance) influences the time sockets are kept lingering around.

When you're on an interactive session, you can use [netstat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat) or [TCPView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview)
to observe the list of allocated sockets on your machine.

In a non interactive scripted environment, using i.e. powershell [get-nettcpconnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-nettcpconnection?view=win10-ps) can be used to obtain the statistics of ports used.

If you are in the CI situation, you want to know when its safe to start new tests, you can stop doing so unless no more than 2/3rd of the client sockets are in time wait:

```
Function waitForTimeWaitSockets() {
    do {
      $TimeWait = (Get-NetTCPConnection -State TimeWait | Measure-Object).Count
      if ($TimeWait -gt 10000) {
        Write-Host "waiting for connections to go away ${TimeWait}"
        Start-Sleep 20
      }
    } while ($TimeWait -gt 10000)
}
```

For sure frequently opening and closing of sockets are not best practice, you should strive to re-use connections, like i.e. HTTP/1.1 persistent connections.

More discussions on that topic can be found [in the microsoft article 'Troubleshoot port exhaustion issues'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/troubleshoot-tcpip-port-exhaust)